# How to set the console's key binding in RStudio?

Tags: r, emacs, rstudio

I have set the keybindings to emacs in the RStudio's global option, but it seems didn't affect the console.
Is there any way to set the console's keybinding to emacs?

Comment: See: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/3556

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no -- the active keybindings currently only take effect within the source editor.